# "to be also so" oder "to be the same"? "Neither...nor"?

Tags: grammar

please, correct this sentence: "I neither drink nor smoke, but you don't have to be also so/the same". By/with this sentence I want to say, that I am both non-drinker and non-smoker, but I would accept you even if you drink and smoke.

Thanks

Comment: What is *oder*?

Comment: @snailboat: It's German for _or_.

Answer (score 1):

How about: 'I neither smoke nor drink, but I accept you no differently should you wish to do either or both of them.'

How you put this very much depends on the person to whom you are speaking, and the circumstances of your wishing to make the remark.

Answer (score 1):

A problem with your sentence is the somewhat faulty parallelism. In the first clause you have the dynamic verbs (*drink / smoke*), and in the second clause you have the copula verb *to be*.

Restoring the parallelism by changing the dynamic verbs to nouns results in:

> I am neither a drinker nor a smoker, but you don't have to be [also
>   so/the same].

As to the complement of the second copula, I find *so too* better than *also so* (which is the typical German word order of *auch so*):

> I am neither a drinker nor a smoker, but you don't have to be so too.

And *the same* works too:

> I am neither a drinker nor a smoker, but you don't have to be the
>   same.

Of course, there are other, more circumlocutory ways of expressing the same sentiment, as WS2 has indicated.

Comment: It seems that English is not really able to carry through a negated also-type parallelism from an already negated condition … which is perhaps not so strange, ’cause that’s a lot of negation. No matter how you phrase this (short of full rewritings, as WS2’s suggestion), it is going to be clumsy and awkward. How about, “I neither drink nor smoke, but you don’t have to not do so, too” for verbal trippiness? More realistically, I think I’d say, “I neither drink nor smoke, but it’s okay if you do”.

Comment: @Janus, You will have noticed that I avoided the alternative parallelism, which would have resulted in the horrible contortion _you don’t have to not do so, too_. And, yes, I think your suggestion is the most natural way to express the OP's sentiment.

Comment: “You don’t have to not do so, too” is almost Adamsesque.